# Boot repair hanging on purge kernels

Tags: boot-repair

When trying to fix ubuntu boot, boot repair is stuck on purge kernels. 
My  boot info is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/15330285/

Answer (score 0):

Few hints from your pastebin:

1. Disable secure boot in BIOS
2. Run the installation of Ubuntu in UEFI mode
3. Some issue with your Logical volume drives for "ubuntu-vg-root" and
   "ubuntu-vg-swap_1" may be you should not try something else but the
   default option for installation of Ubuntu Linux